# Excel VBA add entire row and average

Tags: excel, average, vba

Lets say I want to average every non empty cell on sheet 1 column j how would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=AVERAGE(Sheet1!$J:$J)`should be all you need! :-)

Comment: +1, from the help for AVERAGE(): "If a range or cell reference argument contains text, logical values, or empty cells, those values are ignored; however, cells with the value zero are included."

Answer (score 0):

Let's do a `SumProduct` and `Count -IF` for the **non-zero** numbers only. In this solution, it also consideres negative numbers (SumProduct formula). Then use those two results to count given that `AVERAGE` is good yet it takes zeros in to consideration. If you don't have zeros but just texts and numbers, you are better off with `AVERAGE`, otherwise give this a try and adjust the logic accordingly (to consider negative numbers or not):

[image]

- Depending on the version you are using, you can try out [`AVERAGEIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/averageif-function-HA010047433.aspx) as well.